# C array 64 bit increment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have:

```
uint64_t *list;

if((list = malloc(10 * sizeof(uint64_t))) == NULL){
    errx(1, "malloc");
}
```

I need to populate this array, increment the address of it.

I mean:

```
(*list)++;
list = 1;
(*list)++;
list = 2;
(*list)++;
list = 3;
(*list)++;
list = 4;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You have a block (an array) of 10 uint64_t's, i.e. big integers. You have a pointer to the array. If you increment `list`, you'll lose the block (array), so either you need a second pointer, or just use it as an array. list[0] = 1, list[1] = 2; is okay.

Comment: A simple for-cycle? Like... `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list[i] = (unit_64_t)i;`

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to say that I can't use a loop or normal way: list[0] = 1; list[1] = 2;

Comment: How I can do this by using a second pointer?

Comment: "I forgot to say that I can't use a loop or normal way" -- If this is a homework problem, then tag it with the "homework" tag so we know not to answer it for you.

Comment: it's not my homework, it's part of a big problem, and I'm putting here just what do you need to know, I'm saving your time and don't flooding

Answer (score 3):

You can use the allocated memory like a normal array:

```
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 2;
/* etc. */
```

**Edit:**
What you are doing is increase the first entry in the "array" which probably contains a value you don't expect, then you reassign the pointer so it no longer points to your allocated memory, and so on. Also, if you really want to "increment the address" of the allocated memory, it's just simple as `list++`, however this is also changing the pointer so you loose the original allocated address and can not free it later (unless you save it.)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list[i] = i+1;
}
```